# Python win32com don't know name of module

Tags: python, api, win32com, zune

I was looking for a python Zune(The windows media thing) api, when I looked at the COM browser in pythonwin. I found something called ZuneWmdu Type Library (1.0).
I used makepy on that lib, it generated a file

```
9FE20C05-81CE-46D7-9C56-FD97A865BBB8x0x1x0.py
```

in

```
python 2.7.3\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py
```

I have no idea what to pass into

```
 win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('???')
```

I tried calling

```
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('9FE20C0581CE46D79C56FD97A865BBB8')
```

Resulting in an exception (pywintypes.com_error)

(The x0x1x0 part of the .py file seemed unrelated)

I tried the same with

```
win32com.client.gencache.GetModuleForCLSID('9FE20C05-81CE-46D7-9C56-FD97A865BBB8')
and
win32com.client.gencache.GetModuleForProgID('9FE20C0581CE46D79C56FD97A865BBB8')
```

Both returning None.
I'm stuck here, I need to either find what the library is called (for itunes, you'd call:

```
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('iTunes Application')
```

for example)
or how to call the module with the GUID

Or even someone to tell me that I'm doing something completely wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the CoClass can be found in the comments of the generated file (where they are based on the information from `pythoncom.ProgIDFromCLSID`).

I don't have Zune but, if, for instance I run

```
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule('{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}', 0, 1, 0)
```

this will generate a file called `420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228x0x1x0.py` from which I can dig out the relevant names:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.6>grep 'known by' *.py
420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228x0x1x0.py:# This CoClass is known by the name 'Scripting.Dictionary'
420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228x0x1x0.py:# This CoClass is known by the name 'Scripting.Encoder'
420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228x0x1x0.py:# This CoClass is known by the name 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'
```