# win32com get the list of available applications

Tags: python, win32com

there is a good construct, allows to control win32com objects, like

```
win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
```

... etc.
Is there a way to get full list of available applications (*.Application) ?

UPD. Possible solution to get list via scanning registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for CLSID entries.

```
import winreg
from collections import OrderedDict
def myScan():
    
    result = OrderedDict(); i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            a1 = winreg.OpenKey(aReg, winreg.EnumKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, i))
            if i%1000==0:
                print(i,'processing')
            j = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    #print(j)
                    a2 = winreg.EnumKey(a1,j)
                    if a2=='CLSID':
                        kkkey = winreg.EnumKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,i)
                        vvvalue = winreg.EnumValue(winreg.OpenKey(a1,a2),0)
                        result[kkkey] = vvvalue
                        break
                    j+=1
                except OSError:
                    break
            i+=1
        except OSError:
            break
    return result

result = myScan() #candidates
print(len(res)) # 3363
keys_ = list(result.keys())
#retrieving part of result
for i in keys_[:10]:
    print(i,'=>',result[i])
"""
AccClientDocMgr.AccClientDocMgr => ('', '{FC48CC30-4F3E-4fa1-803B-AD0E196A83B1}', 1)
AccClientDocMgr.AccClientDocMgr.1 => ('', '{FC48CC30-4F3E-4fa1-803B-AD0E196A83B1}', 1)
AccDictionary.AccDictionary => ('', '{6572EE16-5FE5-4331-BB6D-76A49C56E423}', 1)
AccDictionary.AccDictionary.1 => ('', '{6572EE16-5FE5-4331-BB6D-76A49C56E423}', 1)
Access.ACCDAExtension => ('', '{73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9}', 1)
Access.ACCDCFile => ('', '{73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9}', 1)
Access.ACCDCFile.14 => ('', '{73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9}', 1)
Access.ACCDEFile => ('', '{73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9}', 1)
Access.ACCDEFile.14 => ('', '{73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9}', 1)
Access.ACCDRFile.14 => ('', '{73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9}', 1)
"""
```

filtering list by code below (long and possibly unsafe operation), list can be got:

```
import pywintypes
for i in range(len(keys_)):
    try:
        if i%100==0: print(i,'processing')
        app = win32com.client.Dispatch(keys_[i]) #possibly unsafe; for example, word.Quit() is necessary to do
        finalList.append(keys_[i])
    except pywintypes.com_error:
        pass
```

Comment: in your updated code, what is aReg variable?

Comment: areg=winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Answer (score 13):

You might find it helpful to use a dedicated COM browser. For instance, you can use the COM browser bundled with `win32com` to investigate available type libraries and their interfaces:

```
from win32com.client import combrowse
combrowse.main()
```

[image]

For information on how to go from the type library CLSID to the ProgID needed when dispatching, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17225798/5085211).

Comment: But not all 'classnames' can be opened with dispatch, please explain why. Should it have subfolder "CLSID" to be dispatched?

Comment: Hm, yeah, I was going to point you towards `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node`, but that actually also contains unregistered keys. The COM browsers such as the one mentioned and `oleview` are probably better bets. Let me edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Note: calling `combrowse.main(modal=True)` did work for me (without the `modal=True` it'd not really be interactive).