# How to move desktop icons with python?

Tags: python, winapi, com, pywin32

I am making a python program that moves the desktop icons using `LVM_SETITEMPOSITION` from `winapi` but I have a problem with `commctrl.LVM_SETITEMPOSITION` and it gives me an error `'int' object is not callable`. Here is my code:

```
import win32gui
import commctrl
from time import sleep
from ctypes import wintypes

hd = wintypes.HWND

hd = win32gui.FindWindow("Progman", None)
hd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hd, 0, "SHELLDLL_DefView", None)
hd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hd, 0, "SysListView32", None)

i = 0
while i < 1000:
  commctrl.LVM_SETITEMPOSITION(hd, 0, i, i)
  i+100
  sleep(1)
```

Comment: `LVM_SETITEMPOSITION` is not a function call. It's an enum value to be passed via SendMessgae.

Comment: `win32gui.SendMessage`?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Isn't there an api for this?

Comment: Try `SelectAndPositionItems` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-selectandpositionitems

Comment: [Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933).

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, but unfortunately, pywin32 (https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) doesn't define `IFolderView` (it does define all others like IShellView, etc.). So calling this API requires some extra python module development (C/C++)...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setitemposition what about this?

Comment: @sim The question is tagged [tag:winapi]. Can we not assume that user know how to interface with it?

Comment: @IInspectable - the issue here (as I see it) is 99% users of Python only know how to interface with winapi using Python extra modules such as pywin32 (which is ubiquitous with Python+Windows users). Since pywin32 doesn't define IFolderView, user can't do much but write some native code to enable IFolderView for pywin32.

Comment: @SimonMourier If you have the wrong tools, spend some time to get the right ones, no?

Comment: You've been told how to manipulate the positions of desktop icons. There is exactly one supported way to do so. Throwing random messages at random implementation details isn't going to solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - sure. I actually asked pywin32 maintainer if I could help here: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1340

Comment: `win32api.SendMessage(hd, commctrl.LVM_SETITEMPOSITION, 0, (i << 32) + i)`? Don't forget to check the results.

Comment: @CristiFati this works but it only changes the x position and not the y position of the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way (using *COM*) is way more painful than the shortcut I took (still at the end of the answer).

Resources:

- [[SO]: How to move desktop icons using winapi on C? (@IInspectable's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043631/4788546)

  - Based on Raymond Chen's [[MS.DevBlogs]: Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933))
- [[SO]: Return a list of all files from the selected Explorer Window with pywin32 (@zett42's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968304/4788546)
- [[SO]: win32com get the list of available applications (@fuglede's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810380/4788546)
- *MS* *doc* (lots of). Mentioning:

  - [[MS.Learn]: IFolderView interface (shobjidl_core.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifolderview)
  - [[MS.Learn]: IShellFolder interface (shobjidl_core.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder)
- *PyWin32* *doc*:

  - [[GitHub.MHammond]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32)
  - [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)

I started "translating" code from the 1<sup>st</sup> *URL*. Everything went fine til the point of getting *IFolderView*, which is not wrapped by *PyWin32*'s *COM* extensions, hence yielding:
***TypeError: There is no interface object registered that supports this IID.***

I tried to work around it by [[SO]: Implementing a COM interface in Python (@SimonMourier's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75183560/4788546), but no success.

So, I was only left with the option of adding *IFolderView* (partial) support myself. *PR* is **[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - IFolderView COM client](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/2181)** (**merged to *main*** on *240220*).

After building the *shell.pyd* locally (containing the above changes), I was able to get the same behavior using the following script (**which works fine**).

*code01.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import msvcrt
import sys
import time

import pythoncom
import win32com.client as wcomcli
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon


SWC_DESKTOP = 0x08
SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH = 0x01

CLSID_ShellWindows = "{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}"
IID_IFolderView = "{CDE725B0-CCC9-4519-917E-325D72FAB4CE}"
IID_IShellView = "{000214E3-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"


def main(*argv):
    shell_windows = wcomcli.Dispatch(CLSID_ShellWindows)
    hwnd = 0
    dispatch = shell_windows.FindWindowSW(
        wcomcli.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_I4, shellcon.CSIDL_DESKTOP),
        wcomcli.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_EMPTY, None),
        SWC_DESKTOP, hwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH,
    )
    service_provider = dispatch._oleobj_.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IServiceProvider)
    browser = service_provider.QueryService(shell.SID_STopLevelBrowser, shell.IID_IShellBrowser)
    shell_view = browser.QueryActiveShellView()
    print(shell_view.GetCurrentInfo())
    folder_view = shell_view.QueryInterface(IID_IFolderView)
    #print(folder_view.QueryInterface(shell.IID_IShellView))
    items_len = folder_view.ItemCount(shellcon.SVGIO_ALLVIEW)
    print(f"ItemCount: {items_len}")
    for i in range(items_len):
        item = folder_view.Item(i)
        print(f"Item {i:2d}\n  {item}")

    print(f"Spacings: {folder_view.GetSpacing(300, 300)}, {folder_view.GetDefaultSpacing()}")

    item = b"\x1fx@\xf0_d\x81P\x1b\x10\x9f\x08\x00\xaa\x00/\x95N"  # "Recycle Bin" equivalent (in my case)
    #item = 0  # May also be the index (still "Recicle Bin" equivalent)
    #item = 1

    print(f"Item {item} position: {folder_view.GetItemPosition(item)}")
    for i in range(0, 1080, 16):
        print(i)
        folder_view.SelectAndPositionItem(item, (i, i), shellcon.SVSI_POSITIONITEM)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q071905594]> "c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code01.py
> Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> (1, 1075839524)
> ItemCount: 8
> Item  0
>   b'\x1fx@\xf0_d\x81P\x1b\x10\x9f\x08\x00\xaa\x00/\x95N'
> Item  1
>   b':\x00\r\x08\x00\x00NX\x95\xa4 \x00ADOBEA~2.LNK\x00\x00T\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbemV\xa2\xbcRX\xe1h.\x00\x00\x00\xd8\x96\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00k\xc7(\x00A\x00d\x00o\x00b\x00e\x00 \x00A\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00b\x00a\x00t\x00.\x00l\x00n\x00k\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00'
> Item  2
>   b':\x00\xae\x00\x00\x00\x87O\x96I&\x00desktop.ini\x00H\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbe\x87O\xdcITX.m.\x00\x00\x00{\xb2\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x86)\xbf\x00d\x00e\x00s\x00k\x00t\x00o\x00p\x00.\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00'
> Item  3
>   b':\x00\xe4\x08\x00\x00TXtm \x00MICROS~1.LNK\x00\x00V\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbesQ\xd1=TXtm.\x00\x00\x00s\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\xf0Q\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00 \x00E\x00d\x00g\x00e\x00.\x00l\x00n\x00k\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00'
> Item  4
>   b'2\x00\x19\x04\x00\x00wSiN \x00CONNEC~1.LNK\x00\x00\x86\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbewSiNRX\xe1h.\x00\x00\x00\xa7\x8d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\xe5>\x00C\x00o\x00n\x00n\x00e\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00 \x00t\x00o\x00 \x00Q\x00C\x00_\x00A\x00I\x00C\x001\x000\x000\x00_\x006\x004\x00.\x001\x008\x007\x00.\x002\x001\x003\x00.\x001\x009\x004\x00.\x00l\x00n\x00k\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00'
> Item  5
>   b'2\x00\x1a\x01\x00\x00\xafR+\xae&\x00desktop.ini\x00H\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbe\xaeR\xeb\x01TX.m.\x00\x00\x00\xd9k\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\xa35\x00d\x00e\x00s\x00k\x00t\x00o\x00p\x00.\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00'
> Item  6
>   b'2\x00\x9c\x04\x00\x00mV\x94\xb0 \x00TOTALC~1.LNK\x00\x00f\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbemV\x94\xb0RX\xe1h.\x00\x00\x00\x9bo\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001\xbf\x01\x01T\x00o\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00 \x00C\x00o\x00m\x00m\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00r\x00 \x006\x004\x00 \x00b\x00i\x00t\x00.\x00l\x00n\x00k\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00'
> Item  7
>   b'2\x00\x8e\x04\x00\x00mV\x94\xb0 \x00TOTALC~2.LNK\x00\x00X\x00\t\x00\x04\x00\xef\xbemV\x94\xb0RX\xe1h.\x00\x00\x00\x9co\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001\xbf\x01\x01T\x00o\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00 \x00C\x00o\x00m\x00m\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00r\x00.\x00l\x00n\x00k\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00'
> Spacings: (75, 101), (96, 16)
> Item b'\x1fx@\xf0_d\x81P\x1b\x10\x9f\x08\x00\xaa\x00/\x95N' position: (13, 2)
> 0
> 16
> 32
> 48
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- I don't know how *Win* divides the screen into tiles, so I don't know how to make the icon move at any iteration (but that's beyond the question scope, and it was similar in the old approach). I'm incrementing the *X* / *Y* coordinates by 16 for no particular reason
- An item can be specified by its data (that is used in the underlying *WinAPI* implementation). But since that data (that gibberish string in the above output) makes no sense to the user, I added functionality to also use its index. If you want to use it by name, check this code (*code02.py*, "stolen" from [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - (main) com/win32comext/shell/test/testShellFolder.py](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/com/win32comext/shell/test/testShellFolder.py)) out:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import sys

  from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon


  def main(*argv):
      sf = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
      print("Shell Folder is", sf, dir(sf))
      for i, e in enumerate(sf):
          print(f"Item: {i}\n  Name: {sf.GetDisplayNameOf(e, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL)}\n  Data: {e}")

      # And get the enumerator manually
      objs = sf.EnumObjects(0, shellcon.SHCONTF_FOLDERS | shellcon.SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS | shellcon.SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN)
      print(objs, dir(objs))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print(
          "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
              " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
              64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
              sys.platform,
          )
      )
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```
- **Check [[SO]: How to change username of job in print queue using python & win32print (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71684828/4788546)** (at the end) for ways of moving forward with the above patch
- Didn't try it on new *Win 11* builds as I don't have it

---

##### Original answer

<s>Sorry, I misread *WORD* (as *DWORD*) in</s> [[MS.Docs]: LVM_SETITEMPOSITION message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-setitemposition)<s>, so I shifted too much to the left. 
Here's a working example (which should move the item on the leading diagonal on the desktop).</s>

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import msvcrt
import sys
import time

import commctrl as cc
import win32gui as wgui


def main(*argv):
    search_criteria = (
        (0, "Progman", None),
        (0, "SHELLDLL_DefView", None),
        (0, "SysListView32", None),
    )
    wnd = 0
    for crit in search_criteria:
        wnd = wgui.FindWindowEx(wnd, *crit)
        if wnd == 0:
            print("Could not find child matching criteria: {:}".format(crit))
            return
    idx = 0
    for i in range(0, 1000, 16):
        lparam = (i << 16) | i
        print("{:d} - 0x{:08X}".format(i, lparam))
        wgui.SendMessage(wnd, cc.LVM_SETITEMPOSITION, idx, lparam)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

Comment: There's ONE thing I love about Windows 11: It teaches folks what an implementation detail is in a way that cannot be ignored. This code has always been wrong, and with Windows 11 it also stopped working. See [How to move desktop icons using winapi on C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76020228) for the correct solution.