# How to get the windows desktop icons position in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, winapi

I need to get the desktop icons (x, y) coordinate position in windows 11 using python 3.9.

I used LVM_GETITEMPOSITION to get the position of the icons using python, but it outputs the value 0 for all the icons. But when used LVM_GETITEMCOUNT to get the count of desktop icons it worked fine.

Here's my code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
from commctrl import LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, LVM_GETITEMPOSITION
import pywintypes
from uint import Uint
import win32gui
GetShellWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.GetShellWindow


class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
                ("y", c_int)]

def get_desktop():
    shell_window = GetShellWindow()
    shell_dll_defview = win32gui.FindWindowEx(shell_window, 0, "SHELLDLL_DefView", "")
    if shell_dll_defview == 0:
        sys_listview_container = []
        try:
            win32gui.EnumWindows(_callback, sys_listview_container)
        except pywintypes.error as e:
            if e.winerror != 0:
                raise
        sys_listview = sys_listview_container[0]
    else:
        sys_listview = win32gui.FindWindowEx(shell_dll_defview, 0, "SysListView32", "FolderView")
    return sys_listview

def _callback(hwnd, extra):
    class_name = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
    if class_name == "WorkerW":
        child = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "SHELLDLL_DefView", "")
        if child != 0:
            sys_listview = win32gui.FindWindowEx(child, 0, "SysListView32", "FolderView")
            extra.append(sys_listview)
            return False
    return True

def get_item_count(desktop):
    return win32gui.SendMessage(desktop, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT)

def get_item(desktop, point_buffer, icon_count):
    if desktop:
        for i in range(icon_count):
            point_buffer = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.wintypes.POINT(0, 0))
            ret = win32gui.SendMessage(desktop, LVM_GETITEMPOSITION, i, point_buffer)
            if ret != 0:
                x = point_buffer.contents.x
                y = point_buffer.contents.y
                print("x, y: ", x,y)

desktop = get_desktop()
icon_count = get_item_count(desktop)
point = POINT()
point_buffer = pointer(point)  
get_item(desktop, point_buffer, icon_count)
```

And the output I get:

```
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 0
```

Is this method okay or is there any better way to do this in python?

Comment: The `LVM_GETITEMPOSITION` message lives in the `WM_USER` range. As such, the system won't marshal pointers across process boundaries for you. The pointer you're passing is valid in *your* process, but is meaningless inside the Explorer process. It'll error out, at best, and corrupt random memory otherwise. A better solution is to use the provided interface: [`IFolderView::GetItemPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-getitemposition) (full sample [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933)).

Comment: How to use IFolderView::GetItemPosition in python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71974682/4788546